# Google Play Current Installs Higher Than Active Installs

Tags: android, google-play

I currently have an android application available on the Google Play store.  Under Current/Total installs, the "current" installs is **higher** than the "total" number of installs.  How exactly did this happen?  Does this mean that people are sharing the application / getting it without paying?  Or is this normal somehow?

[image]

I understand that current installs means the total number of people who still have the application, minus any uninstalls, whereas the total amount is every install with uninstalls.  So how exactly can by current be higher than my total?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current installs is the number of **devices** where your app is installed.

Total installs is the number of **users**.

That means that some users installed your app on more than one device.

---

If you hover over the question mark in Google Play, it is explained in the tool tip:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it does. But doesn't change my point that when you compare the number of devices to number of users, the former can be higher.

Comment: Thanks Szymon. My mistake. I didn't read his question carefully enough. I suppose the two additional users could even be himself actually, in case he installed his new application from Google Play on more than one of his own devices.

Comment: Yes, that's likely. It's what happened to me - I had 2/1 in beta as I was the only user with 2 devices.

Comment: Oh man I feel silly...  That's totally it.  Thanks guys/girls.